# How to handle Loop for error during Requests in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-requests

I am trying to get data from an website and I am with an issue that I can't pass trough an array.

I need to run `requests.get(value[0])`, `requests.get(value[1])`, `requests.get(value[N])`.
But when I got an error this loop just STOP.

The code:

```
import requests

value = ['http://teste', 'http://cast4.audiostream.com.br:8651/status-json.xsl']

try:
  for item in value:
      response = requests.get(item)
      print(response)
except:
      print('response')
```

And those two URLs are a real case, if I run this script will explode an exception, but the second URL is a valid URL, I've tried some other options using `while`, putting `pass` instead of `print()` but without success, how can I handle that to let my loop for, keep doing its job??

Thanks!!!

Comment: I need to pass trough all items from an array, the real error is that http://test do not exists, and this code do not allowing me to continue to run that.

Comment: Maybe you mean to have the `try...except` clauses in the loop, instead of around it. But your question isn't completely clear to me either...

Comment: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='teste', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4f840886a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the places of `for` and `try`, like:

```py
for item in value:
  try:
      response = requests.get(item)
      print(response)
  except:
      print('response')
```

Also, avoid using bare excepts. Observe what error the code is raising, then change your except to catch that exception, e.g:

```py
for item in value:
  try:
      response = requests.get(item)
      print(response)
  except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
      print('timeout exception')
```

Add more exceptions by new exceptions you get. Or if you don't want your program to stop when you encounter a new exception, at least print the error:

```
except Exception as error:
  print(error)
```

Comment: You got that, I changed try position, and added
```
except Exception as error:
  print(error)
```
and it works!! Thank you =)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are puting the try statement outside the for loop. Changing the code to this may work:

```
import requests

value = ['http://teste', 'http://cast4.audiostream.com.br:8651/status-json.xsl']
for item in value:
    try:
        response = requests.get(item)
        print(response)
    except:
         print('response')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the ".com" in your first URL

```
import requests

value = ['http://teste', 'http://cast4.audiostream.com.br:8651/status-json.xsl']

for item in value:
    try:
        response = requests.get(item)
        print(response)
    except:
        print('Error')
```

Comment: It's almost there, I just added '.com' at the end of 'http://teste' but, I was looking for some way to fix that without this kind of solution, because if the link is broken, I need to keep doing my loop for without handle any part of my link, just adding on database saying "Oh no, this link is wrong, please fix it".

Comment: Oh gotcha, you just need to adjust the position of your try for that

Comment: Basically try to get this URL if it works fine, if not throw an error and continue to the next URL in the list